# Bash Using Quotes in Grep/Cut Commands in Scripts

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I have a line similar to this

```
grep -oP "data-context-item-title=.*.data-context-item-id" web.html | cut -d'"' -f2
```

I know this line correctly works since I used it on the terminal and it gave me the desired output. However, I want to put this line in a bash script. so I have this so far

```
title="$(grep -oP 'data-context-item-title=.*.data-context-item-id' web.html | cut -d'"' -f2)"
```

This is a problem because it matched the first "(quotation) with the cut's "(quotation). Is there anyway to avoid it?

Output without the cut function is something similar to this

```
data-context-item-title="Some long title" data-context-item-id
data-context-item-title="Another very long title" data-context-item-id
```

Keep in mind, I can't use any sed or awk commands to replace cut.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using bash, it would be safe enough to use:

```
title=$(grep -oP 'data-context-item-title=.*.data-context-item-id' web.html | cut -d'"' -f2)
```

This will preserve the internal spacing (in particular newlines) in the variable, as you'd be able to see if you did:

```
echo "$title"
```

I'm of the opinion that if you managed to find a UNIX™ 7<sup>th</sup> Edition Bourne Shell to use, then omitting the double quotes around the `$(...)` notation (or, more accurately, the `` `...` `` notation) would not be safe, but it does seem to work safely on modern shells (say those last updated in the current millennium, rather than in the previous one).  The difficulty is in finding an old Bourne Shell on which to verify my now shaky (because distant) recollection.

What puzzles me, though, is that with both `bash` 3.2 (system) and 4.2 (home-built) running on Mac OS X 10.7.5, your code works correctly for me both with and without the double quotes around the `$(...)`.  Which version of `bash` are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: I second the question about what version of bash this is. And to be clear: the important question is what version of bash is running the script, which may not be the same version that's being used interactively.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for delimiter in cut is a double quote not single. Use backlash to escape the actual quote

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm purposely using the double quotation as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Wild suggestion: is it possible one of the quotes in your command isn't a plain ASCII quote, but some sort of Unicode fancy quote (which the shell won't recognize)?

Answer (score 0):

First, to solve the error escape the double quote for `cut`:

```
title="$(... | cut -d \" ...)"
```

However, you're using grep's PCRE, so you can use lookarounds and drop cut altogether:

```
title=$(grep -oP '(?<=data-context-item-title=").*?(?=" data-context-item-id)' web.html)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's a typo or not but you seemed to have forgotten the closing parenthesis for `$(...)`

Comment: yeah that was a typo. just fixed it

Comment: so does the first `"` still match the cut's `"`? The line works fine on my machine.

Comment: yes, it still matches the first " with cut's ". When I make more lines of code, it thinks they're all in the quotation and never terminated.

Comment: Not sure why it does that. I copy pasted the `title=...` line and I get "Some long title" and "Another very long title". Are you sure you didn't mistype anything?

Comment: this is more appropriate as a comment. Others may downvote. Good luck to all.